# E(SSB) in single factor ANOVA

Tags: anova

$SSB=\sum_i \sum_j (\bar x_{i.}-\bar x_{..} )^2 =J\sum_i(\bar x_{i.}-\bar x_{..} )^2 = \frac1J\sum_i x_{i.} -\frac{x_{..}}{IJ}$

$E(SSB)=E(\frac{1}{j}\sum_{i} (X^2_{i.})-\frac{1}{IJ}X_{..})$ (1)

$= \frac1j\sum_i(E(X^2_{i.})) -\frac1{IJ}E(X^2_{..})$ (2)

$= \frac1j\sum_i(V(X_{i.})+[E(X_{i.})]^2) - \frac1{IJ}(V(X_{..})+[E(X..)]^2)$ (3)

$= \frac1j\sum_i(J\sigma^2 +[J(\mu + \alpha_i)]^2)-\frac1{IJ}(IJ\sigma^2 +(IJ\mu)^2)$ (4)

$=I\sigma^2 +IJ\mu^2 +2\mu J\sum_i(\alpha_i)+J\sum_i\alpha^2_i -\sigma^2-IJ\mu^2$ (5)

$=(I-1)\sigma^2 +J\sum_i\alpha^2_i$ (6)

could someone explain how they go from line (3) to line (4) in this example?